# Java json string to java class

Tags: java, json

How can I convert this json string to java class object?
The json String is stored in database, I need to convert into class object.

```
    {
    "key1": {
      "key11": "value11",
      "key12": "value12",
      "key13": "value13"
            },
    "key2": {
      "key21": "value21",
      "key22": "value22",
      "key23": "value23"
           },
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": [{
          "key1": {
            "key11": "value11",
            "key12": "value12",
            "key13": "value13"
                  },
          "key2": {
          "key21": "value21",
          "key22": "value22",
          "key23": "value23"
            }
           }]
      }
```

Comment: Use JSON parser (like gson). To get more specific answer you need to ask more specific question. What object exactly do you want to get? What have you tried, what problems ware you facing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) Library

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(string);
```

In your case the retrieved string from database is

```
String string =  {
    "key1": {
      "key11": "value11",
      "key12": "value12",
      "key13": "value13"
            },
    "key2": {
      "key21": "value21",
      "key22": "value22",
      "key23": "value23"
           },
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": [{
          "key1": {
            "key11": "value11",
            "key12": "value12",
            "key13": "value13"
                  },
          "key2": {
          "key21": "value21",
          "key22": "value22",
          "key23": "value23"
            }
           }]
      }
```